# Conditional validation requirement by referring 2 different column fields

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns

I have sharepoint with 3 mandatory fields.

Status_1 is with open and closed
Status_2 is with high, low and medium
Status_3 is opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4

I need the column validation formula for when choose Status_3=opt1, it should allow to save the item only when Status_1=open and Status_2=high

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in Validation settings.

```
=IF(OR(AND(Status_3="opt1",Status_1="closed",Status_2="high"), AND(Status_3="opt1",Status_1="closed",Status_2="low"), AND(Status_3="opt1",Status_1="closed",Status_2="medium"), AND(Status_3="opt1",Status_1="open",Status_2="low"), AND(Status_3="opt1",Status_1="closed",Status_2="medium")), FALSE, TRUE)
```